# Quitar espacio en funcion copiar js

Tags: javascript

amigos, tengo mi funcion copiar:

```
//funcion copiar texto
const copyText = (e) => {
window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
let range = document.createRange();
range.selectNode(e.target.previousElementSibling);
window.getSelection().addRange(range);
document.execCommand('copy');
window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
}
```

pero al momento de realizar la copia, me agrega 2 saltos (espacios)

```
-13.830035,-171.767184
```

asi tal cual, como puedo hacer para quitar esos espacio generados al ejecutar la funcion?
saludos y gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0):

En javascript cada `String` constructor contiene una funcion `.trim()` que quita los espacios de cada texto, podrias hacer algo asi

```
console.log("hola mundo")
//hola mundo

console.log("homa mundo".trim()) 
//holamundo
```

Comment: Solucione agregando esto: selectNodeContents

Comment: si ya solucionaste tu problema tambien puedes responder a tu propia pregunta

Comment: .trim() solo resta espacios al final, no elimina espacios...